# How to add module in Metasploit?

Tags: metasploit

I'm using Metasploit on Windows, but I can't load ms17_010_eternalblue. So I download it from github.

How can I add that modules to my Metasploit?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I had to copy the exploit file into `metasploit-framework` directory, following its structure, you can use any of the following commands as reference, but you have to check the current path in your system.

```
cp ms17_010_eternalblue.rb metasploit/apps/pro/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/metasploit-framework-4.14.19/modules/exploits/windows/

cp ms17_010_eternalblue.rb /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/smb/ms17_010_eternalblue.rb
```

Ref: https://github.com/ElevenPaths/Eternalblue-Doublepulsar-Metasploit/issues/30